# Ambiguity in the use of ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I have following problem with using of AngularJS ngRepeat. 
The issue can be viewed in this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/9rmEs/2/

The user can choose character and after this get all combination 
of chosen characters in alphabet. Eg:

A - A-B, A-C, A-D and etc.

B - B-A, B-C, B-D and etc.

Everithing works properly but when user change value of selected 
character the combination does not get updated. I solved this problem 
with adding following code.

```
<span style="display: none;">
        {{item.combionations = getCombinations(item)}}
</span>
```

And "hack" it. But there must be normal solution. 
I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations.

Best regards.

Comment: Check out [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: check this version http://jsfiddle.net/9rmEs/5/

Comment: @Sebastian You should really add that as an answer, with an explanation of what you did, you seem to have solved the OP's problem

Comment: @JMK You are right. I added an answer to explain what I changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

In case you plan to do more complex calculations based on the selection this simplified approach would not work. In general it is also better to encapsulate state in some data structure. In your case you could design a structure like this:

{ letter: "A", combinations: ["A-B", "A-C", ... ] }

To update the combinations array you can use `ng-change="updateItem(item)"` and some update function. Whenever you change the selection the array `combination` gets updated:

```
$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
  item.combinations = getCombinations(item.letter);
}
```

I put this in a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6FK5/).

---

You can easily solve this issue by using the model you bound to `ng-select` in the `ng-repeat`.

In the select you used `item.model`. Angular will update its value in the scope whenever you change the selection.

```
<select data-ng-model="item.model" ng-init="item.model=allLetters[0]" ng-options="value for value in allLetters">
</select>
```

When you use the same scope variable in `ng-repeat` you should get the desired behavior.

```
<div ng-repeat="letter in allLetters">
  {{item.model}}-{{letter}}
</div>
```

Take a look an the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rmEs/5/).

Comment: Note there is a problem: the `$scope.created[<x>].combionations` do not get updated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you compute `combionations` once at the begenning (`ng-init="item.combionations=getCombinations(item)"`). After that it never gets updated when you change `item.model`.

You could solve this problem (and also make sure `created[...].combionations` is kept up-to-date) like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in created">
    <div ng-repeat="combination in item.combionations = getCombinations(item)">
        {{combination}}
    </div>
    ...
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9rmEs/6/)**.